# Bind condition dynamically to component's template

Tags: angular, angular-components

I built a `PageHeaderComponent` which will be built based on the `buttons` array.

While I was able to bind the `(click)` event correctly to the method in the parents component I am struggling to bind the condition for the `[disabled]` status of the `button-secondary` correctly.

In my case the disabled status will be set correctly **initially**. But in case the condition changes **at runtime** the `disabled` status won't be updated. What would be the correct way to bind the disabled condition?

**parent.component.ts**

```
    @Component({
        templateUrl: 'parent.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['parent.component.sass'],
        encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
    export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
        ...

        selectedTasks: TaskViewModel[] = [];
        buttons: Button[] = [
            {
                click: () => this.openModal(),
                disabled: !this.selectedTasks || this.selectedTasks.length == 0,
                icon : 'plus-circle-solid',
                text: this.translateService.instant('component.tasks.new-task')
            },
            {
                click: () => this.openDeleteTaskModal(),
                disabled: !this.selectedTasks || this.selectedTasks.length == 0,
                icon : 'times-circle',
                text: this.translateService.instant('component.tasks.new-task')
            },
    
        ]
        openModal() {
        
        }

        ...
    }
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<div page-header
    title="{{'component.tasks.title' | translate}}"
    [buttons]="buttons">
</div> 

...
```

**page-header.component.html**

```
<div class="row page-header">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let button of buttons" >
        <button-secondary 
            text="{{ button.text | translate}}"
            (click)="button.click($event)"
            icon = "icon icon-{{button.icon}}"
            [id]="button.id"
            [disabled] = "button.disabled"
         >
         </button-secondary>
     </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create getters for that, but you have to add an unwanted variable to your buttons because of the scope of getters.

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-brgakv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
buttons: Button[] = [
  {
    _parent: this,
    click: () => this.openModal(),
    get disabled() { return !this._parent.selectedTasks || this._parent.selectedTasks.length == 0 },
    icon: 'plus-circle-solid',
    text: this.translateService.instant('component.tasks.new-task'),
  },
  {
    _parent: this,
    click: () => this.openDeleteTaskModal(),
    get disabled() { return !this._parent.selectedTasks || this._parent.selectedTasks.length == 0 },
    icon: 'times-circle',
    text: this.translateService.instant('component.tasks.new-task'),
  },
];
```

Comment: Really the problem is that the "array" not change, else one element of the array, so Angular can not know this change. The classic solution is create a new array with the same values using spread operator: `//after change the array;`, `this.buttons=[...this.buttons]`

Comment: Wrong, change detection happens on outputs like (click), so a getter will get updated. IT would have taken you 5 seconds to test this on the stackblitz though.

Comment: Yes, if you use a getter it's true, the "clasic" mode is when you don't use getters

Comment: Then feel free to make your own answer about this, instead of implying there's an issue with mine :)

Comment: Sorry, I was lazy to answer and comment you there's another way, apologies